# How to penalize for empty fields in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have to calculate the consistency of racing car drivers during the whole season. My DataFrame consists of 10 columns (10 circuit names) and for each of those columns I have the standard deviation in lap time the driver posted in that circuit. In other words, how consistent the driver is from lap to lap. In races the driver did not finish the field is blank.

So far I have calculated their average season consistency by averaging all 10 columns. However, not finishing a race should affect a driver's consistency negatively and I do not know how to implement that.

Comment: Maybe not the best solution, but the naive heuristic would be `df.fillna(some_really_bad_score)`.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It might belong on [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it relates to statistics

Comment: I think you need to decide how to treat "not finished" records? Can you fill in the blanks with paper and pen (and maybe a calculator)? Then you should add that to your question. If not, the question has nothing to do with python, pandas dataframe, or even programming in general.

Comment: You might find this useful: [Handling null values when taking averages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183257/handling-null-values-when-taking-averages)